# Nodejs using child_process runs a function until it returns

Tags: node.js, express, parallel-processing, child-process

I want this kind of structure;

express backend gets a request and runs a function, this function will get data from different apis and saves it to db. Because this could takes minutes i want it to run parallel while my web server continues to processing requests.

i want this because of this scenario:

user has dashboard, after logs in app starts to collect data from apis and preparing the dashboard for user, at that time user can navigate through site even can close the browser but the function has to run until it finishes fetching data.Once it finishes, all data will be saved db and the dashboard is ready for user.

how can i do this using child_process or any kind of structure in nodejs?

Comment: It depends upon what the operations are that "gather" data for the dashboard.  If that's all asynchronous disk or network requests, then just make sure all your I/O is asynchronous and you're probably fine without involving more processes.  node.js can have many many requests in process at the same time as long as they are not CPU intensive and are all using async I/O.

Comment: @jfriend00 it gets data from instagram api, but say user has many photos to get this will take time. After the function starts to run user can be able to reload or close the page or even logs out but the function has to keep running until it gets all photos from api and saves them to db. My frontend is angular so, i will check only isUserInitialized value in db with angular and show a message the user 'dashboard is being prepared ' once it finishes dashboard will be ready.

Answer (score 1):

Since what you're describing is all async I/O (networking or disk) and is not CPU intensive, you don't need multiple child processes in order to effectively serve multiple requests.  This is the beauty of node.js.  With async I/O, node.js can be working on many different requests over the same period of time.

Let's supposed part of your process is downloading an image.  Your node.js code sends a request to fetch an image.  That request is sent off via TCP.  Immediately, there is nothing else to do on that request.  It's winging it's way to the destination server and the destination server is preparing the response.  While all that is going on, your node.js server is completely free to pull other events from it's event queue and start working on other requests.  Those other requests do something similar (they start async operations and then wait for events to happen sometime later).

Your server might get 10 different async operations started and "in flight" before the first one actually starts getting a response.  When a response starts coming in, the system puts an event into the node.js event queue.  When node.js has a moment between other requests, it pulls the next event out of the event queue and processes it.  If the processing has further async operations (like saving it to disk), the whole async and event-driven process starts over again as node.js requests a write to disk and node.js is again free to serve other events.  In this manner, events are pulled from the event queue one at a time as they become available and lots of different operations can all get worked on in the idle time between async operations (of which there is a lot).

The only thing that upsets the apple cart and ruins the ability of node.js to juggle lots of different things all at once is an operation that takes a lot of CPU cycles (like say some unusually heavy duty crypto).  If you had something like that, it would "hog" too much of the CPU and the CPU couldn't be effectively shared among lots of other operations.  If that were the case, then you would want to move the CPU-intensive operations to a group of child processes.  But, just doing async I/O (disk, networking, other hardware ports, etc...) does not hog the CPU - in fact it barely uses much node.js CPU.

So, the next question is often "how do I know if I have too much stuff that uses the CPU".  The only way to really know is to just code your server properly using async I/O and then measure its performance under load and see how things go.  If you're doing async things appropriately and the CPU still spikes to 100%, then you have too much CPU load and you'll want to either use generic clustering or move specific CPU-heavy operations to a group of child processes.

Comment: But in the scenario that user close the browser or reloads the page, how do i keep function running in the backend ?

Comment: @invincible - I don't understand the question.  Your backend keeps running regardless of what happens in a browser.  So, if you have a `setInterval()` loop in the backend, it keeps going no matter what.

Comment: But i dont know what time the fetching will took exactly, how can i provide a time to setInterval without knowing it, at the interval time has passed and the fetch is not done at that time, it will restart the fetching. Can you give a general logic to do this ?

Comment: @invincible - I have absolutely no idea what you're asking about in this latest comment.  There is nothing in your question that describes this part of the problem in any way.  You are apparently assuming I know something about what you're trying to do that has not been described in your question.

Comment: Okay, sory for misunderstanding, let me describe what i want to achieve, user logs into site and authorize instagram account, we get user photos and other datas likes, comments from instagram api with accesstoken and save them to db but what happens if user has 2000 3000 photos , it will take time to get all data. After user authorize with instagram we will provide the basic user info that comes with first response from instagram like username, id etc but we wont respond with medias immediately, we just start a function in backend for fetching and user can continue to use site during this time

Comment: After all fetching done at some time then user will be able to see all medias.but during fetching even user close the browser , fetching function has to run until finishes

Comment: @invincible - OK, I get that now.  But, what's the question?  A server just keeps doing it's job, no matter what a browser does so I don't understand what the issue is.   Also, this looks like a completely different question that what you originally asked so maybe it should be in a new question.

Comment: can cron jobs be used for that purpose?

Comment: @invincible - You can use either `setTimeout()` of `setInterval()` for scheduling code to run sometime in the future.  I can't help you any further without a detailed description of what problem you're trying to solve.  I have absolutely no idea what you want to use cron jobs for.   So far all you've describe is a user logs into the site and you kick of a sequence of events to gather their photos and other data.  No need for anything special there.  Just start the action on your server when the user logs in.